# Cannot view dotnetbar controls on form

Tags: vb.net, object, controls, dotnetbar

I have a dotnetbar version 10.0.0.3 and when I add it on control toolbox window and drag it to my form this always happen.

[image]

as you can see, LabelX1, TextBoxX1 and ButtonX1 are in the form, but in the design it doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem.
I think it's something about the dll.

I installed `DevComponents.DotNetBar2` on my PC (it's a setup called `DotNetBarSetup`) and then
I got the dll-file from the HD
`C:\Program Files (x86)\DotNetBar for Windows Forms\DevComponents.DotNetBar2.dll`

Next, you have to drag the dll-file from windows explorer to the toolbox in Visual studio.

That should do the trick.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in log time. finally i found the exact solution for this problem. The solution is install .NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0) before install DotNetBar for windows form.

Hope this helps all the developers facing this problem.